# MySQL populating linked tables

Tags: mysql

I'm new to MySQL and as part of an exercise I have had to create a database for a flight reservation system, I'm trying to create a customer which means inserting a row into 3 linked tables.  I'm trying to do this as a transaction but my syntax seems very clunky.  Is there a better way to do this?
Here's my transaction (which does work) but I feel there must be a FAR more elegant way to do this:

```
START TRANSACTION;
SET @account_id = NULL;
INSERT INTO ezy_account (account_id, username, password)
VALUES (@account_id = @account_id, 'customer@mysite.com',AES_ENCRYPT('password1', 'encryptionkey'));

SET @payment_id = NULL;
INSERT INTO ezy_payment_details (payment_details_id, payment_type, account_id, card_number, name, valid_from, expiry)
VALUES (@payment_id = @payment_id, 1, (SELECT account_id FROM ezy_account WHERE username ='ngray@mysite.com'), '1234567890123456', 'chris cust', '2018-03-00', '2021-10-00');


INSERT INTO ezy_customer (customer_id, payment_details, title, first_name, last_name, email_address, address, address_continued, city, postcode, country, dialling_code, phone_number, account_id, easyjet_plus_number, preferred_airport1, preferred_airport2, preferred_airport3)
VALUES (NULL, (SELECT payment_details_id FROM ezy_payment_details WHERE card_number ='1234567890123456'), 1, 'chris', 'customer', 'customer@nmysite.com', '123 Road Street', NULL, 'london', 'SE1 4HG', 7, 7, '1898765432', (SELECT account_id FROM ezy_account WHERE username ='customer@mysite.com'), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
COMMIT;
```

Comment: I advice you to read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) and provide us with example data and expected results.

Comment: we really mainly take questions about _problems_ with code - i.e. things which don't work as expected. If you simply want to improve on the layout of your otherwise working code, you could check if your question would fit better on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: One thing I would suggest you could do though (to avoid accidentally returning the wrong row, for example) is, instead of the inner selects, just get the last ID you inserted and use that instead (you can put it into a variable, and then use the variable value in your next query). See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id

Comment: You cannot insert to more than 1 table at a time so I don't think there are any better options. There is no duplicate checking going on here - but maybe you don't require it.